# Callback on calling notifyListeners when using ChangeNotifier

Tags: flutter, flutter-change-notifier

I need to listen to a callback or something after every `notifyListeners` called, while i am using  Change notifier

it's is something like `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_)` but this in case of using setState or rendering the frame for the first time

Comment: If you're using Riverpod Notifier, you can .listenSelf and execute code on every state update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears to that you can register `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_)` under the `consumer` widget for `ChangeNotifierProvider` , so in that case after every `notifyListeners` the consumer will be called and a callback for it  will be registered after it the frame is already rendered.